# Scraped data not printing to csv/xlsx file

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv, xlsx

I'm trying to scrape data and store it in a csv or xlsx file, but when I run my code, the file returns empty.

When I used a `break` to stop the iterator after one cycle, I found the code held a row of the data I want. The end goal is to write this data, row-by-row, into the file. If it helps to know, I'm using beautifulsoup4.

Here is the code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import xlsxwriter

url = 'https://www.rwaq.org/courses'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
base = 'https://www.rwaq.org'

course_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'course-info'})
course_links = [base + item.h3.a['href'] for item in course_div]
row = 0
for link in course_links:
    inner_page = requests.get(link)
    inner_soup = BeautifulSoup(inner_page.content, 'html.parser')
    course_name = inner_soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'page-title'}).h2.text
    course_lecturer_name = inner_soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'instructor-details'}).a.text.strip()
    course_desc = inner_soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'lecture_desc'}).p.text.strip()
    if inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(4) div.row-fluid ul'):
        course_manhag = inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(4) div.row-fluid ul').text
    elif inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(4) div.row-fluid p'):
        course_manhag = inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(4) div.row-fluid p').text
    else:
        course_manhag = ''

    if inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(5) div.row-fluid ul'):
        course_require = inner_soup.select_one(
            '#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(5) div.row-fluid ul').text
    elif inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(5) div.row-fluid p'):
        course_require = inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(5) div.row-fluid p').text
    else:
        course_require = ''

    if inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(6) div.row-fluid ul'):
        course_out = inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(6) div.row-fluid ul').text
    elif inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(6) div.row-fluid p'):
        course_out = inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(6) div.row-fluid p').text
    else:
        course_out = ''

    course_company = inner_soup.select_one(
        'body div.container-fluid div div.subject-cover div.cover-info div div.subject-organization p a').text
    course_date_from = inner_soup.select_one('p.subject-date').text.strip()[3:16]
    if inner_soup.select_one('p.subject-date') is True:
        course_date_to = inner_soup.select_one('p.subject-date').text.strip()[31:]
    else:
        course_date_to = ''
    course_status = inner_soup.select_one('p.subject-date span').text
    course_lecturer_link = [base + li.a['href'] for li in
                            inner_soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class': 'instructor-details'})]
    course_iframe = inner_soup.select_one('iframe').attrs["src"]
    course_promo_link = course_iframe[:24] + 'watch?v=' + course_iframe[30:course_iframe.find('?')]
    wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file001.xlsx')
    sheet = wb.add_worksheet()
    sheet.write(row, 0, course_promo_link)
    sheet.write_row(row, 1, course_lecturer_link)
    sheet.write(row, 2, course_desc)
    sheet.write(row, 3, course_out)
    sheet.write(row, 4, course_status)
    sheet.write(row, 5, course_name)
    sheet.write(row, 6, course_date_from)
    sheet.write(row, 7, course_date_to)
    sheet.write(row, 8, course_manhag)
    sheet.write(row, 9, course_require)
    row += 1
    wb.close()
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well I get errors running your code so I can't test. But the first initial thing I would try is take `wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('file001.xlsx')` and `wb.close()` out of the `for` loop. My initial thought is you're over writing the file each time. So something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import xlsxwriter

url = 'https://www.rwaq.org/courses'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
base = 'https://www.rwaq.org'

course_div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'course-info'})
course_links = [base + item.h3.a['href'] for item in course_div]

#Initialize your file/workbook
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/file001.xlsx')
sheet = wb.add_worksheet()

row = 0
for link in course_links:
    inner_page = requests.get(link)
    inner_soup = BeautifulSoup(inner_page.content, 'html.parser')
    course_name = inner_soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'page-title'}).h2.text
    course_lecturer_name = inner_soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'instructor-details'}).a.text.strip()
    course_desc = inner_soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'lecture_desc'}).p.text.strip()
    if inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(4) div.row-fluid ul'):
        course_manhag = inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(4) div.row-fluid ul').text
    elif inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(4) div.row-fluid p'):
        course_manhag = inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(4) div.row-fluid p').text
    else:
        course_manhag = ''

    if inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(5) div.row-fluid ul'):
        course_require = inner_soup.select_one(
            '#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(5) div.row-fluid ul').text
    elif inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(5) div.row-fluid p'):
        course_require = inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(5) div.row-fluid p').text
    else:
        course_require = ''

    if inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(6) div.row-fluid ul'):
        course_out = inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(6) div.row-fluid ul').text
    elif inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(6) div.row-fluid p'):
        course_out = inner_soup.select_one('#organization div.course-content div:nth-child(6) div.row-fluid p').text
    else:
        course_out = ''

    course_company = inner_soup.select_one(
        'body div.container-fluid div div.subject-cover div.cover-info div div.subject-organization p a').text
    course_date_from = inner_soup.select_one('p.subject-date').text.strip()[3:16]
    if inner_soup.select_one('p.subject-date') is True:
        course_date_to = inner_soup.select_one('p.subject-date').text.strip()[31:]
    else:
        course_date_to = ''
    course_status = inner_soup.select_one('p.subject-date span').text
    course_lecturer_link = [base + li.a['href'] for li in
                            inner_soup.find_all("div", attrs={'class': 'instructor-details'})]
    course_iframe = inner_soup.select_one('iframe').attrs["src"]
    course_promo_link = course_iframe[:24] + 'watch?v=' + course_iframe[30:course_iframe.find('?')]

    sheet.write(row, 0, course_promo_link)
    sheet.write(row, 1, course_lecturer_link)
    sheet.write(row, 2, course_desc)
    sheet.write(row, 3, course_out)
    sheet.write(row, 4, course_status)
    sheet.write(row, 5, course_name)
    sheet.write(row, 6, course_date_from)
    sheet.write(row, 7, course_date_to)
    sheet.write(row, 8, course_manhag)
    sheet.write(row, 9, course_require)
    row += 1

# Close it once all rows are written    
wb.close()
```

Comment: yes i think i'm doing that and i will try your code i hope it work thank you @chitown88